# CRTP - Can I make a private method?

Tags: c++, crtp, static-polymorphism

I'm implementing a static polymorphism:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    void method() {
         // do something
         impl();
         // do something else
    }
    void impl() { // intended to be private
        static_cast<T*>(this)->impl();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
     void impl() { // intended to be private
     }
};
```

This code is a static implementation of a dynamic polymorphic classes where void impl() was virtual and private.

I've achieved polymorphism (static). But I had to make the method void impl() public in order to allow access to it from a Base class. I want method void impl() to be private again. Can it be done?

UPDATE:
I don't want to write

```
friend class Base<Derived>;
```

in Derived class, because it allows Base access to all members of Derived.

Comment: you can add `friend class Base<Derived>` to the `Derived` class.

Comment: I think this is often over design, but you can refine friendship using [attorney-client idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Friendship_and_the_Attorney-Client), if you think friend ship is too much.

Comment: I appended my answer to reflect your suggestion, @Oliv

Answer (score 7):

Adding a line to your `Derived` class:

```cpp
class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
private:
     void impl() { // intended to be private
     }
     friend class Base<Derived>;
};
```

which will specify the base class as a friend, allows me to compile the code with `impl` being private.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comment by @Oliv, the implementation of the Attorney-Client idiom would look like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Attorney;

template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    void method() {
        // do something
        impl();
        // do something else
    }
private:
    void impl() { // intended to be private
        Attorney<T>::impl(*static_cast<T*>(this));
    }
};


class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
private:
    void impl() { // intended to be private
    }
    friend class Attorney<Derived>;
};

template<typename T>
class Attorney {
private:
    friend class Base<Derived>;

    static void impl(Derived & c) { // add additional parameters as needed by impl
        c.impl();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! But isn't this solution too strong? Now Base<Derived> has access to all members of Derived.

Comment: Though I'm not sure how to expose only `impl`, I reserve doubts that a design using the crtp here would require only a single method should be private, and not the rest, so in practicality won't be applied.

Comment: In that case, a potential design, and more transparent, is making two crtp classes, one that needs access to private methods and the other that doesn't.

Comment: Why in the definition of the template class Attorney do we use the Derived class by name?

Comment: And is there any potential benefit to making the Attorney a protected nested-class of Base<T>, maybe at least so the name isn't visible to classes that don't derive from Base<T>, although I'm not sure that could ever be a problem.

Comment: @stephematician as opposed to defining it in general? Using the Derived class by name here is a direct solution when trying to expose Base::impl to Deriv::impl, and not doing anything more. Although, it can be done for general derived type T, which is given.

Comment: Attorney can be a nested class, the example here just mirrors all the example implementations one might find on wikipedia, etc. If attorney is visible to all, then classes that need private access but don't derive will also be able to call `impl`. One thing that would change with nested is changing the friend declaration to be `Base<T>::Attorney`.